# How do I change the DatePicker style in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, datepicker, uidatepicker

I implemented a DatePicker in my IUViewController and I changed the 'datepicker locale' to France - French but it's still written in english. I did the same with a datepicker for Time only and I still get AM and PM.
Do I have to change it directly in the .m file ?
Like this :
   DatePicker.locale = french; // I just invented this, it probably doesn't exist.

Comment: How do you fetch/create your locale?

Comment: I don't understand. I just put a datepicker in the view, and then with the interface builder I selected locale - France (french) but the datepicker didn't change.

Comment: Check the locale-settings of your MainWindow file. I had this problem and added localization within MainWindow.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Check**, if the correct locale is actually set:

Add the following code to your viewController to check what the actual locale is after loading the nib file (I'm assuming you did setup an IBOutlet for your DatePicker named `datePicker`):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSLog(@"%@", self.datePicker);
  NSLog(@"%@", self.datePicker.locale.localeIdentifier);
}
```

This should log `fr_FR` in your case.

2) **Test it on a real device!** This is a point, were the simulator could be wrong.

3) Test with **various language / region settings** on the phone.

Comment: I have a UIDatePicker instance and it's linked to the DatePicker. And I'm not using nib files (I think so). I just used the IB and I created a .m/.h file for the UIViewController with the DatePicker.

Comment: updated answer. do you understand this? than try it and show us the results.

Comment: here's the result: 2012-11-08 16:13:08.920 test[15847:f803] <UIDatePicker: 0x68a5820; frame = (0 244; 320 216); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x68a9a60>>
2012-11-08 16:13:08.921 test[15847:f803] <__NSCFLocale: 0x6888640>

Comment: @frénésie -- If you're not using NIB (.xib) files, what did IB produce?

Comment: @HotLicks he did not understand. not so important. @frenesie try logging `self.datePicker.localeIdentifier` so we see which one it is.

Comment: This is the error I get when i try logging it: Property 'localeIdentifier' not found on object of type 'UIDatePicker *'

Comment: ah sry, this is correct: `self.datePicker.locale.localeIdentifier `

Comment: I get fr_FR, but the months are still written in english, as for the clock it's still with AM/PM.

Comment: Have you tried this on an actual device, or only in the simulator? And also: Have you tried to put your simulator language in french, also the date&time settings?

Comment: OK my bad. I set the language in french and it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: well if you set the locale, it should work without setting the device language. but still you should test this on an acutal device. please accept the answer, if your issues are resolved.

Comment: (You know, that you do not need to set a locale at all, if you want to use the system language!?)